# Calling Python functions from C++

Tags: c++, python, callback, boost-python

I am trying to achieve call Python functions from C++. I thought it could be achieved through function pointers, but it does not seem to be possible. I have been using `boost.python` to accomplish this.

Say there is a function defined in Python:

```
def callback(arg1, arg2):
    #do something
    return something
```

Now I need to pass this function to C++, so that it can be called from there. How do I write the code on C++ side using `boost.python` to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it might have any name:

Pass it to a function that takes a `boost::python::object`.

```
bp::object pycb; //global variable. could also store it in a map, etc
void register_callback(bp::object cb)
{
      pycb = cb;
}
```

If it is in a single known namespace with a consistent name:

```
bp::object pycb = bp::scope("namespace").attr("callback");
```

`bp::object` has `operator()` defined, so you call it just like any function

```
ret = pycb()
```

Comment: Thnks Matthew, I have an additional question. Here the python object is being called from the same thread. What if python object was global and was being called from a different thread?

Comment: That is possible, although somewhat beyond the scope of this question. I recommend investigating the C/Python API's PyGILState_* family of functions. Unlike Boost-Python, Python has very good docs. If you still need more help, ask another question.

Comment: For Future viewers: Someone eventually asked that other question, and I answered it. Look over here:  stackoverflow.com/questions/8009613/boost-python-not-supporting-parallelism/8011153#8011153

Comment: @MatthewScouten can you please give a simple working example of above topic so I can understand well, as I am very new to C++ and I know more about the Python.

Comment: Thank you. Now if only boost gave a simple EXAMPLE in their documentation of how you do this... At least we have Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Not a clue. But you can use [`PyObject_Call()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Call) to call it once you have the function object.

Comment: If you have a `boost::python::object`, you can just use its `operator()` to call it.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used it before, but the reference manual has a section called [Calling Python Functions and Methods](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/v2/callbacks.html) which seems to show how to do this.

Comment: Boost python documentation is largely out of date and extremely bad even where it is up-to-date.

Comment: That page does not show you a Python function. It just shows you how to call one with an already bound object. Not exactly a "simple example".

Answer (score 1):

I used `PyRun_SimpleString("myFunction()")` as quick hack, as my function's name was known, took no args and lived in the `__main__` namespace. Note you additionally need to get lock GIL if you are multi-threaded.