# Use Python code in C/C++

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm working in an embedded Linux environment and I have some Python code which I would like to use. My Python code is just doing some math, not using any library other than Numpy and the common ones.

Is there any way to build up a library that I can call from C or C++ code?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html may be of interest.

Comment: Also consider to actually make a C/C++ library to use in Python code (= extending as opposed to embedding). It's easy to overlook that this scenario can actually be more interesting for many applications

Comment: Check out [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/)!

Comment: Duplicate or at least interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331599/calling-python-functions-from-c

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Embedding the CPython interpreter into a C or C++ program is actually pretty straightforward.

The [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) has some complete examples.

Also, check out [`SWIG`](http://www.swig.org/) and [`Boost.Python`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/).

Comment: Cython may be worth to mention here, too. Even it's typically used the other way round.