# Embedding c++ in Python

Tags: c++, python

Let's say I have a C++ function that prints "Hello", how can I embed the function so I can use it in Python code? I've read the Python documentation for Extending but i really didn't understand that documentation.

Help please ;<

Comment: -1:  Please show us what you have tried, in the form of an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Python code in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117978/use-python-code-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html). You can compile a library that you can include in your python script. Then from there you could call that C++ function.