# How can you assign the input of a user added by a value in a single line?

Tags: c++

I want to assign the input of the user added by a value to a variable in a single line . Is there anyway that I could possibly do this?

```
std::cout << "Please enter a number";
std::cin >> number; //thinking of adding 10 to number in this same line.
```

Comment: Python and C++ are different.

Comment: Sure, write a input function like python does and put that code in there.

Comment: honest question: why do you care about it being in a single line?

Comment: @hop Exactly, readability of code is more important, most of the times.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117978/use-python-code-in-c-c

Comment: @amrit I don't think that is what the OP wants.

Comment: int x; cout << "Please enter a number to add to 10": cin >> x; cout << x + 10;

Comment: You could write `cout << x + []{ int i; cin >> i; return i; }();`, but this is no better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments you can write a function of your own and utilize the [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int input(const std::string& s){
    std::string tempstr;
    std::cout << s;
    std::getline(std::cin, tempstr);
    return std::stoi(tempstr);
}
int main(){
    int num = 10 + input("Please enter a number to add to 10:");
    std::cout << num;
}
```

Error checking omitted for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function for this in C++, but you can write it:

```
int input(string prompt)
{
   int x;

   cout << prompt;
   cin >> x;

   return x;
}
```

Then you can call it, let say in main function like this:

```
int main()
{   
   int num = 10 + input("Please enter a number to add to 10 : ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite of a curiosity.One answer can be like mentioned above like you can develop a function "input" which returns the intake value . But if you want in in one liner without any function.
    `enter code here`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int x,num;
   if (cout<<"enter new number") if(cin>>x) num=10+x;
   cout<<num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, without extra variables nor functions (although a function is the best way):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = (cout << "Input: ") && (cin >> num) ? num + 10 : 0;

    cout << num;

    return 0;
}
```