# float point mul (*10) with adds and shifts

Tags: c++, c

My question is simple: I can do `2 * 10` with shift and addition by `(2 << 2) + 2` but I have no idea how to get `2.2 * 10` with shift and addition. Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

-khan_gl

Comment: If you are using double or float as I think, you can't simply. The binary representation of floating point number is a standardish nightmare. If you can deal with fixed point numbers, then it's easy.

Comment: Somewhat Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720668/fast-multiplication-division-by-2-for-floats-and-doubles-c-c

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `(x << 3) + (x << 2)` is `x * 12`, not `x * 012`.

Comment: oh! misstake. (*10) is (x << 3) + (x << 1)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

`2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + 2.2 + (0 << 1)`

Kidding aside, you can't as you can't shift floats in C++/C. Well, you can (via nasty type-punning), but then you're getting into undefined behavior.

Also, there's no point in doing it. If you're doing multiplication then just use `*`. The compiler will transform it into the most efficient form.

Comment: What's `0 << 1` for? I don't think it's UB, the standard requires integer operands for shift operators.

Comment: @Alex khan wanted a shift in there so I complied ;) The UB comes from casting the float to an int to perform the shift.

Comment: @Pubby: I see no undefined behavior.  There is no *cast* from `float` to `int`.  `(0 << 1)` is of type `int`, with the value 0.  The result is implicitly converted from `int` to `double` (not `float`), which yields `0.0`.  What problem do you see?

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, guess it must be with type punning then. My example wasn't meant to show UB.

Comment: @Pubby: I think I see what you mean; you're talking about something like `*(unsigned*)&float_object << 1`, which certainly is UB.  I'm going to update your answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question at all,

2.2 = 2 + 2/10

Therefore, 2.2 * 10 = 2*10 + 2*10/10 = 2*10 + 2 = 22.

You can do division with shifts and subtractions.

Answer (score 1):

On a modern CPU, floating point numbers are represented in a format called "IEEE 754".

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754
- http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

At the core of IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic are bit shifts and integer arithmetics.  If you're patient you can write a naive implementation of IEEE 754 ALU in C.  You might find this thread interesting:

- [Is there an open-source c/c++ implementation of IEEE-754 operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186788/is-there-an-open-source-c-c-implementation-of-ieee-754-operations)